# How much will a sheet of gold distort under its own weight?

Tags: material-science, estimation, metals

The central question I'm seeking an answer to is: what is the minimum thickness required for a rectangular sheet of pure gold, 131cm × 79cm and simply supported on all four sides, so that the centre does not sag by more than 1cm under its own weight? If someone can answer this, that'd be fantastic.

I have found a useful calculator at https://www.engineersedge.com/material_science/rectangular_plate_uniform_load_13643.htm but the results I got seemed counterintuitive. Not being a materials engineer I'm assuming I've misunderstood something or applied the wrong formula:

$$y = \frac{(0.142 × P × a^4)}{(E × t^3 × (2.21(a/b)^3 + 1)}$$

y = deflection (m)

P = force/area (Pa) = density of gold (19,320 kg/m) × thickness (m) × gravitational acceleration constant (9.81 m/s^2)

a = minor length (0.79 m)

b = major length (1.31 m)

E = Young's modulus (7.9 × 10^10 Pa)

t = thickness (m)

By my (mis?)calculation this would mean even 1cm thick gold would only deflect by 8.9 × 10^-4 m. To me that's very surprising for such a soft metal -- am I in error?

Comment: -I'm not sure this fits here. It might work better as a question on our [engineering.se] stack, but wait and see what others say.

Comment: The density of gold in SI units is 19,320 kg/m^3. That seems like it may fix your problem.

Comment: When all else fails, check your units, and check your assumptions. You don't have units listed for some of your input parameters. You haven't checked that the gold plate continues to deform in the linear elastic regime.

Comment: @RC_23 thanks! I've corrected this and updated the result. As I can't experimentally or otherwise confirm this is still correct I'll leave the question open for other possible corrections but really appreciate this pick up!

Comment: That sounds like a very reasonable answer. Gold is soft for a metal but it's still a metal. 1cm thick plate of gold would be VERY stiff. Obviously you can't experiment with Gold but you can run the same calculation and measurements for a much cheaper material (like ABS, iron, etc.)